# Network Manager multiple NIC swapping profiles on boot

Tags: 22.04, network-manager

(Ubuntu 22.04)
I am using NetworkManager to configure two network interfaces: one onboard set to use Profile *A* and a USB adapter on Profile *B*. Every time I reboot they switch: onboard NIC set to *B*, USB adapter to *A*.

There is nothing interesting in the system log. The interfaces receive consistent names and MAC addresses each boot. Both profiles have "connect automatically" checked. I tried setting `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="net.ifnames=0"` - now instead of swapping between *A* and *B* the devices are assigned one of the other available profiles at random (*C*, *D*, etc.)

Here is my `lshw` if it helps:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Cannon Lake PCH CNVi WiFi
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 10
       serial: 5c:80:b6:76:d8:51
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.19.0-41-generic firmware=46.ea3728ee.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0- latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:b4618000-b461bfff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 15
       serial: 80:fa:5b:78:bb:7a
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.19.0-41-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=10.0.20.81 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:18 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b4404000-b4404fff memory:b4400000-b4403fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: e
       bus info: usb@1:2.4
       logical name: eth1
       serial: 00:e0:4c:df:f5:17
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.12.13 duplex=full firmware=rtl8153b-2 v1 10/23/19 ip=137.128.161.66 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
```

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue with Debian 11.7 (latest, up to date). It is kind of maddening. Have to manually swap networks every boot. We need a way to select a specific network profile (fixed) for each network adapter and force NM to stick with it.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: @fviktor I have not noticed this behavior recently. I don't know if it was resolved by an update or if it stopped happening by chance. I agree it is frustrating.

Comment: Somehow it disappeared for me as well. Maybe fixed by an update. It would be nicer to know the actual root cause and why/how it has gone exactly, just to make sure it don't come back at the worst time.